# ruby bundle install error when installing openproject

Tags: ruby, openproject

I'm trying to install Open Project and I'm stuck at the bundle install part for ruby.

When I run "bundle install", I get the following error:

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/openproject/openproject/vendor/cache/ruby/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/openproject/openproject/vendor/cache/ruby/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and
>   Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector
>   -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.

I've tried installing the gem itself but get the same error.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If you need any additional info, please let me know what command I need to run to get the information and I'll provide it immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the content of gem_make.out? (path is listed in your post)

Comment: i was actually able to resolve this by downgrading from centos 7 to centos 6.5 - i guess it didn't like the newer version

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to resolve this by downgrading from CentOS 7 to CentOS 6.5 — I guess it didn't like the newer version.